# Qual é o nome do operador :: (dois-pontos duplos) em PHP?

Tags: php

No PHP, parece que esse operador `::` tem um nome hebraico (sei lá por qual motivo alguém usaria o hebraico), `Paamayim Nekudotayim`.

Tenho problema sempre quando tenho que explicar para alguém o nome desse operador, já que não sei a pronúncia do nome dito acima.

Sempre digo: *Dois dois-pontos*

Existe algum outro nome pelo qual pode ser chamado o operador `::`?

Comment: Foi um programador israelense que inseriu a constante `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` (= double-colon = duplo dois-pontos) numa versão antiga do parser do Zend e criou a confusão. Era frequente o erro *Unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM...*. Não sei se hoje mudaram esse nome internamente.

Comment: Não mudaram @bfavaretto. Esse erro costuma ocorrer (eu uso o PHP 5.5)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bem, de acordo com o manual, é o `Operador de Resolução de Escopo`, ou - o termo mais simples sugerido pelo manual - `dois pontos duplo`.

[Link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) do manual em PT-BR.

Comment: _Operador de Resolução de Escopo_ é mais bonito do que _dois dois-pontos_

Comment: "dois ponto duplo", muito mais simples, objetivo e fácil de entender.

Comment: "double colon" também.