# Chamar função de classe: MinPDO::connect();

Tags: php, classes, funções

Tenho uma classe chamada `MinPDO` e dentro dela uma função chamada `connect`:

```
class MinPDO {

    public $sgbd = "mysql";
    public $dbhost = "localhost";
    public $dbname = "minpdo";
    public $dbuser = "root";
    public $dbpass = "";

    public function connect() {
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("{$this->sgbd}:host={$this->dbhost};dbname={$this->dbname};charset=utf8;", $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            return $conn;
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            echo "<br><b>Error:</b> " . $ex->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Como posso chama-la assim?

```
MinPDO::connect();
```

No momento estou fazendo assim:

```
$mnpdo = new MinPDO();
$mnpdo->connect();
```

Segundo alguns programadores seria mais útil chama-la da primeira forma, mas como faço isso?

Comment: DEclarando as variaveis e o método como `static`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::`, indica a chamada de um método ou propriedade estática ou constante. Basta adicioanar  a plavara chave `static`.

```
public static function connect()
```

Para montar corretamente o construtor do PDO, pode transformar as variáveis de instancia em membros estáticos também ou que significa que essas propriedades estarão disponíveis através da classe e não de um objeto em especifico.

```
$conn = new PDO(self::$sgbd.":host=".self::$dbhost.";dbname=".self::$dbname.";charset=utf8;", self::$dbuser, self::$dbpass);
```

**Relacionado:**

[Quando usar self vs $this em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/575/91)

[Qual é o nome do operador :: em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86236/91)

Comment: É importante ressaltar que a chama dos atributos deve ser alterada tambem, sem o `$this->` como ele está fazendo.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe, eu ia falar exatamente isso, eu já tinha tentado colocando somo `static`, daí ele reclamos exatamente disso, como eu deveria colocar as variáveis?

Comment: Verdade não tinha notado isso, vou editar.

Comment: Funcionou, vou dar uma olhada nos links.. Editei a resposta, pois o `self` não é reconhecido quando usamos `{}` para indicar variáveis, só por concatenação.